# Why is my webpage not fitting the screen?

Tags: html, css

My page has a width of 1920px on the body element.  My 15" Macbook Pro supposedly has a resolution of 2880x1800.  Why do I need to zoom out to see the entire page?

Comment: Is it theoretical question?

Comment: No, its a real question.

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual resolution? That seems very large for 15". The highest I can go is 1920x1200 and it was defaulted to 1440x900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixel density of many modern screens is very high. If you viewed content intended for more traditional screens on them using native pixel resolution, you would end up with pin sharp text that was too small for most people to read.

Macbook Retina displays are, by default, scaled so software treats them as having a resolution of 1440x900. This means that 10px high text (for instance) uses 20 physical pixels and is still large enough to read, but is sharper than it would be on a screen with 1440x900 physical pixels.

[image: Mac Display Preferences]

Comment: Ahh I see.  Thank-you for explaining.

Comment: Do I need to add a viewport meta tag to make it fit properly then?

Comment: No. You need to treat it like it is a 1440x900 display.